# %04d - am I using the ffmpeg input file ranges wrong?

Tags: ffmpeg

Am I doing it wrong?

`ffmpeg -framerate 10 -i Reiher_%04d.jpg -vf "scale=720:-1:flags=lanczos,split[s0][s1];[s0 ]palettegen[p];[s1][p]paletteuse" Reiher.gif`

gives

```
[image2 @ 0x7ffff37fdd00] Could find no file with path 'Reiher_%04d.jpg' and index in the range 0-4
Reiher_%04d.jpg: No such file or directory
```

Below are both the dir listing and the full ffmpeg output.

```
# ls
Reiher_0380.jpg  Reiher_0400.jpg  Reiher_0420.jpg  Reiher_0440.jpg  Reiher_0460.jpg  Reiher_0480.jpg  Reiher_0500.jpg
Reiher_0381.jpg  Reiher_0401.jpg  Reiher_0421.jpg  Reiher_0441.jpg  Reiher_0461.jpg  Reiher_0481.jpg  Reiher_0501.jpg
Reiher_0382.jpg  Reiher_0402.jpg  Reiher_0422.jpg  Reiher_0442.jpg  Reiher_0462.jpg  Reiher_0482.jpg  Reiher_0502.jpg
Reiher_0383.jpg  Reiher_0403.jpg  Reiher_0423.jpg  Reiher_0443.jpg  Reiher_0463.jpg  Reiher_0483.jpg  Reiher_0503.jpg
Reiher_0384.jpg  Reiher_0404.jpg  Reiher_0424.jpg  Reiher_0444.jpg  Reiher_0464.jpg  Reiher_0484.jpg  Reiher_0504.jpg
Reiher_0385.jpg  Reiher_0405.jpg  Reiher_0425.jpg  Reiher_0445.jpg  Reiher_0465.jpg  Reiher_0485.jpg  Reiher_0505.jpg
Reiher_0386.jpg  Reiher_0406.jpg  Reiher_0426.jpg  Reiher_0446.jpg  Reiher_0466.jpg  Reiher_0486.jpg  Reiher_0506.jpg
Reiher_0387.jpg  Reiher_0407.jpg  Reiher_0427.jpg  Reiher_0447.jpg  Reiher_0467.jpg  Reiher_0487.jpg  Reiher_0507.jpg
Reiher_0388.jpg  Reiher_0408.jpg  Reiher_0428.jpg  Reiher_0448.jpg  Reiher_0468.jpg  Reiher_0488.jpg  Reiher_0508.jpg
Reiher_0389.jpg  Reiher_0409.jpg  Reiher_0429.jpg  Reiher_0449.jpg  Reiher_0469.jpg  Reiher_0489.jpg  Reiher_0509.jpg
Reiher_0390.jpg  Reiher_0410.jpg  Reiher_0430.jpg  Reiher_0450.jpg  Reiher_0470.jpg  Reiher_0490.jpg  Reiher_0510.jpg
Reiher_0391.jpg  Reiher_0411.jpg  Reiher_0431.jpg  Reiher_0451.jpg  Reiher_0471.jpg  Reiher_0491.jpg  Reiher_0511.jpg
Reiher_0392.jpg  Reiher_0412.jpg  Reiher_0432.jpg  Reiher_0452.jpg  Reiher_0472.jpg  Reiher_0492.jpg  Reiher_0512.jpg
Reiher_0393.jpg  Reiher_0413.jpg  Reiher_0433.jpg  Reiher_0453.jpg  Reiher_0473.jpg  Reiher_0493.jpg  Reiher_0513.jpg
Reiher_0394.jpg  Reiher_0414.jpg  Reiher_0434.jpg  Reiher_0454.jpg  Reiher_0474.jpg  Reiher_0494.jpg  Reiher_0514.jpg
Reiher_0395.jpg  Reiher_0415.jpg  Reiher_0435.jpg  Reiher_0455.jpg  Reiher_0475.jpg  Reiher_0495.jpg  Reiher_0515.jpg
Reiher_0396.jpg  Reiher_0416.jpg  Reiher_0436.jpg  Reiher_0456.jpg  Reiher_0476.jpg  Reiher_0496.jpg  Reiher_0516.jpg
Reiher_0397.jpg  Reiher_0417.jpg  Reiher_0437.jpg  Reiher_0457.jpg  Reiher_0477.jpg  Reiher_0497.jpg  Reiher_0517.jpg
Reiher_0398.jpg  Reiher_0418.jpg  Reiher_0438.jpg  Reiher_0458.jpg  Reiher_0478.jpg  Reiher_0498.jpg
Reiher_0399.jpg  Reiher_0419.jpg  Reiher_0439.jpg  Reiher_0459.jpg  Reiher_0479.jpg  Reiher_0499.jpg
# ffmpeg -framerate 10 -i Reiher_%04d.jpg -vf "scale=720:-1:flags=lanczos,split[s0][s1];[s0
]palettegen[p];[s1][p]paletteuse" Reiher.gif
ffmpeg version 4.4.3-alt2 Copyright (c) 2000-2022 the FFmpeg developers
  built with gcc 10 (GCC)
  configuration: --prefix=/usr --libdir=/usr/lib64 --shlibdir=/usr/lib64 --mandir=/usr/share/man --docdir=/usr/share/doc/ffmpeg-4.4.3 --disable-rpath --enable-gpl --enable-version3 --enable-pthreads --enable-shared --disable-static --enable-mmx --disable-nonfree --enable-ffplay --enable-ffprobe --enable-avfilter --enable-avresample --disable-avisynth --enable-bzlib --enable-chromaprint --enable-frei0r --enable-gnutls --disable-ladspa --enable-libaom --disable-libaribb24 --enable-libass --enable-libbluray --enable-libbs2b --enable-libcaca --enable-libcdio --disable-libcelt --enable-libcodec2 --enable-libdav1d --disable-libdavs2 --enable-libdc1394 --enable-libdrm --disable-libflite --enable-libfontconfig --enable-libfreetype --enable-libfribidi --disable-libglslang --enable-libgme --enable-libgsm --disable-libilbc --enable-libjack --disable-libklvanc --disable-libkvazaar --disable-liblensfun --disable-libmfx --disable-libmodplug --enable-libmp3lame --enable-librabbitmq --disable-libmysofa --enable-libopencore-amrnb --enable-libopencore-amrwb --enable-libopenjpeg --disable-libopenmpt --enable-libopus --enable-libpulse --enable-librsvg --disable-librtmp --enable-librubberband --disable-libshine --enable-libsnappy --enable-libsoxr --enable-libspeex --enable-libssh --disable-libtesseract --enable-libtheora --enable-libtwolame --enable-libudev --enable-libv4l2 --enable-libvidstab --disable-libvmaf --enable-libvorbis --enable-libvpx --enable-libwebp --enable-libx264 --enable-libx265 --disable-libxavs2 --enable-libxml2 --enable-libxvid --disable-libzimg --enable-libzmq --enable-libzvbi --enable-lv2 --disable-omx --enable-openal --disable-opencl --enable-opengl --disable-pocketsphinx --enable-sdl2 --enable-v4l2_m2m --enable-vaapi --disable-vapoursynth --enable-vdpau --enable-vulkan --enable-zlib --enable-cuvid --enable-hardcoded-tables --enable-runtime-cpudetect --enable-debug --disable-stripping --enable-pic --extra-cflags='-pipe -frecord-gcc-switches -Wall -g -fPIC -DPIC' --extra-version=alt2
  libavutil      56. 70.100 / 56. 70.100
  libavcodec     58.134.100 / 58.134.100
  libavformat    58. 76.100 / 58. 76.100
  libavdevice    58. 13.100 / 58. 13.100
  libavfilter     7.110.100 /  7.110.100
  libavresample   4.  0.  0 /  4.  0.  0
  libswscale      5.  9.100 /  5.  9.100
  libswresample   3.  9.100 /  3.  9.100
  libpostproc    55.  9.100 / 55.  9.100
[image2 @ 0x7ffff37fdd00] Could find no file with path 'Reiher_%04d.jpg' and index in the range 0-4
Reiher_%04d.jpg: No such file or directory
```

Comment: What is the OS?

Comment: The same problem under both Linux and Windows

Comment: If you want to use it on Linux, you can just use `-pattern_type glob` with  `*` wildcard matches. Does that work for you?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The image2 demuxer, by default, will look for the first image file to have a serial number between 0 and 4 ("*index in the range 0-4*").

You will have to specify the actual start number i.e.

```
-framerate 10 -start_number 380 -i Reiher_%04d.jpg
```

Answer (score 0):

You have to include the image2 filter:

```
ffmpeg -f image2 -framerate 10 -i Reiher_%04d.jpg -vf "scale=720:-1:flags=lanczos,split[s0][s1];[s0 ]palettegen[p];[s1][p]paletteuse" Reiher.gif
```